# Опустить клавишы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как поправить эти кнопки?

```
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Amount</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">-</div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">-</div>
                            <input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теги `input` строчные, а тег `div` в который они помещены блочный, строчные элементы не занимают все место в `div`, а прижимаются к верхней границе `div`-а, поэтому я вставил тег `label`, но скрыл его от глаз, `css`-свойством `visibitity:hidden`.

```html
      <form class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Amount</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">-</div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">-</div>
                            <input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <label style="visibility:hidden">Status</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```